# Simple ant script to compile code isn't finding the lib

Tags: java, ant, war

My project structure is:

```
├── WebContent
│   ├── META-INF
│   ├── WEB-INF
│   │   ├── lib
│   │   └── views
│   ├── css
│   ├── img
├── src
│   └── com
│       └── mycode
│           └── morecode
```

I am trying to compile the code and then have a WAR:

Following is my ant script task for compile, however, it fails and complains at the most basic things like `error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist` However, the code compiles fine in my IDE. So, I suspect that my task isn't configured property in ant.

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
    <mkdir dir="dist" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init" >
    <javac destdir="build/classes" debug="true" srcdir="src">
        <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you don't have the servlet API JAR in your `WEB-INF/lib`, because those classes would normally be provided by the servlet container.  Your IDE will be providing them from somewhere else, but for your Ant build you'll need to get a copy of the [relevant JAR](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.servlet%7Cjavax.servlet-api%7C3.0.1%7Cjar), put it in your project somewhere like `build/lib` (i.e. not under `WEB-INF`) and add it to your `compile.classpath`.